# Making an image appear in a jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp

I currently have a jsp where in m html section I have the following

```
<select>
<%if(size == 1)%>
  <option>None selected</option>
<%if(size > 1)%>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

I also have the following image.

```
<td style="text-align:left">
            <label id="checked" style="color:grey; display:none">
                <img src="images/check.png" width="20px" height="20px"/>
                Checked
            </label>
        </td>
```

My question is that how do I get my image to appear only if the option none is selcted. If 1 is selected then I do not want the image to appear. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this will give you solution for your problem, i have used JQUERY here.

```
 $("#selectID or .selectClass").change(function () { //just use id or class name for select element

    var option=$(this).val();
    if(option=="None selected")
    {
      $("#checked").css("display","block");

    }
    else
    {
       $("#checked").css("display","none");
    }      

});
```